Django rest framework : unable to login user with correct email and password
I am new to Django. I am trying to build a simple login/registration with MongoDB as database. The user is successfully signing up but unable to login using correct password and email.
Here is my serializers.py file
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')

Here is my models.py file
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_doctor', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

Here is my views.py for Login
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def login_view(request):
    email = request.data.get('email')
    password = request.data.get('password')

    user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid email or password'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

It is always shows the Invalid email or password.

looking at your code, it seems like you're not using Django's authentication system for login. You're using the authenticate function, but you're not providing any authentication backend, so it's unlikely to work.

Just try username=email instead of email=email in authenticate(), so try user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password) instead see if it works.

"I am trying to build a simple login/registration with MongoDB as database." How are you plugging the MongoDB ODB? By default, Django uses the Django ORM over SQL.

@ChukwujiobiCanon  I'm using Djongo to connect to the database.

What is your settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL?

@ChukwujiobiCanon, I haven't specified AUTH_USER_MODEL in my settings file. When I attempted to add AUTH_USER_MODEL = "core.User"  (where core is my Django app), I encountered a ValueError stating: "Dependency on app with no migrations: core."

Then makemigrations for core first.

@ChukwujiobiCanon, I've executed makemigrations for the core app and included AUTH_USER_MODEL = "core.User". I'm glad to report that the ValueError mentioning "Dependency on app with no migrations: core" has been resolved. However, despite these adjustments, I'm still encountering the "Invalid email or password" error.
